# SSRS Download from Python Giving Corrupt File

Tags: python, reporting-services, python-requests

When I run my script, it creates a corrupt, not-openable PDF file.

Here is my code, which seems to work for a lot of other people:

```
filename = f'./report.pdf'

username = "myusername"
password = "mypassword"
url = "http://RptServerIp/ReportServerName/reports/Untitled&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF"

r = requests.get(url, auth=HttpNtlmAuth(username, password))

print(r.status_code)

if r.status_code == 200:
    with open(filename, 'wb') as out:
        for bits in r.iter_content():
            out.write(bits)
```

This is a no-parameter test report (and it's called Untitled). The status code is 200 and I've confirmed the login info is correct by changing one character in the password to make it incorrect, which returns a bad status code. If I go to the URL http://RptServerIp/ReportServerName/reports/Untitled in my browser it shows the report, but if I do the full URL http://RptServerIp/ReportServerName/reports/Untitled&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF it gives me an error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: Sadly there's no error or exception, but when I try to open the PDF file it shows unable to open PDF. If I try the same code but switch to .xlsx and Format=Excel it gives a corrupt excel file as well. However downloading it from the ssrs site directly works perfectly. (later edit) The error I get when I go to the URL on my browser is The path of the item '/Untitled&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF' is not valid.

Comment: Does the SSRS instance have a different name than the server it runs on? If not then remove the `/ReportServerName` part

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone that answered, I found a solution that for some reason isn't everywhere on stack overflow.

The URL I was using was something like:

http://ServerIpAddress/Reports/report/Untitled&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF

but it needed to be changed to:

http://ServerIpAddress/Reportserver?/Untitled&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF

The big difference is that the default client name when going through the browser is Reports/{admin-named-subfolder} but the default when using the URL connect is Reportserver? with no subfolder included.